# Return items between date and only if created before another item was deleted

Tags: c#, linq, logical-operators

Say I have a list of items with created and deleted datetimes:

```
  ITEM,   CREATED, DELETED
item 1, 1/1/1999, 1/14/2014
item 2, 1/1/1999, 1/17/2014
item 3, 1/15/2014, NULL
item 4, 1/16/2014, NULL
```

I need a list with the final results, so

Item 3 cancels item 1 out, because it was created after item 1 was deleted, but Item 4 does NOT cancel out item 2 because it was created before item 2 was deleted.

So the end result should be a list with

item 2, item 3, item 4

the code I have now is as follows

```
                int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
                DateTime sdate = new DateTime(year, DateTime.Now.Month - 1, 1);
                DateTime edate = new DateTime(year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);

                var qry = Emails.collection.Where(t => 
                    t.deletedon.HasValue ?
                    t.deletedon.Value >= sdate :
                    t.createdon.Value < edate
                    ).ToArray()
```

But this code includes item 1.
So it includes All items created before the end date that were not deleted unless deleted after the start date.

But if an item was deleted and a new one created, then the list includes both. but I needs to basically replace the deleted one with the created one, so the end result count totals the maximum emails created and active at one time..

```
Emails.Item[] created = Emails.collection.Where(t => t.createdon.Value >= sdate && t.createdon.Value < edate).ToArray();
Emails.Item[] deleted = Emails.collection.Where(t => t.deletedon.HasValue && (t.deletedon.Value >= sdate && t.deletedon.Value < edate)).ToArray();

Emails.Item[] exceptions = deleted.Where(t => created.FirstOrDefault(c => c.createdon.Value >= t.createdon.Value)).ToArray(); ???
```

Comment: I think it's easier to simply modify the collection/copy values into another with a sort like approach; than trying to do a linq where, because for your where to work, you'll need to join the collection with itself to check how the date you're looking at matches with all the other items in the collection. And that's much easier to just handle in a normal loop logic.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I need an except in my linq above.. I am trying to get the exceptions in another list..

Comment: I guess that your problem originates from not having identifiers for the items!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that the cancellation of an item, as you described it, depends on the comparison with another item, and your Where is only checking conditions on each item itself.

Assuming I understood your problem well:

- You need a list of all non-deleted items plus the deleted but not canceled ones.
- An item is considered canceled if there is another item created after its deletion

If that's the case, I would retrieve the non-deleted items first and then the deleted ones separately. Next step will be to filter the deleted items using the creation date of non-deleted ones.

An easy way of doing it so would be to order the non-deleted items by creation date and get the earliest one and use it to discard all deleted items with a deletion date earlier than that.

Final step: Merge both lists.

Comment: yeah, this is in the right direction.. That's basically the conclusion I have been coming to.. still hard to get the exceptions list.. I'll try to understand the process you described..  

In a way, your final descriptions don't sound right.. 
The right way seems to be that I need to get the first item that is created after another item was deleted.. Humm a little confusing

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly but working version..

```
                int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
                DateTime sdate = new DateTime(year, DateTime.Now.Month - 1, 1);
                DateTime edate = new DateTime(year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);

               Emails.Item[] created = Emails.collection.Where(t => t.createdon.HasValue && (t.createdon.Value >= sdate && t.createdon.Value < edate)).OrderByDescending(y => y.createdon).ToArray();
                List<Emails.Item> deleted = Emails.collection.Where(t => t.deletedon.HasValue && (t.deletedon.Value >= sdate && t.deletedon.Value < edate)).OrderByDescending(y => y.deletedon).ToList();
                List<Emails.Item> ex = new List<Emails.Item>();
                foreach (Emails.Item t in created)
                {
                    Emails.Item d = deleted.FirstOrDefault(y => y.deletedon.Value >= t.createdon.Value);
                    if (d != null && t.createdon.Value <= d.deletedon.Value)
                    {
                        deleted.Remove(d);
                        ex.Add(t);
                    }
                }

                //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(created.Count().ToString() + " / " + deleted.Count().ToString() + " / " + ex.Count().ToString());

                var qry = Emails.collection.Where(t => 
                    t.deletedon.HasValue ?
                    t.deletedon.Value >= sdate :
                    t.createdon.Value < edate
                    ).Except(ex).ToArray()
                    .OrderBy(t => t.lastname).OrderBy(t => t.firstname).GroupBy(x => x.company, (key, group) => new { Company = key, Items = group });
```

Anyone know of a way to condense this all?